# Regarding common preservatives and their effect

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

If someone has an average of 1 litre of Coke or Pepsi a day, would this form too much benzene oxide in the person's body or stomach and eventually effect part of their genetics?

Answer (score 3):

Benzene oxide isn't present in Coke or Pepsi.  Some drinks contain sodium benzoate though.  If that is what you're concerned about, there's not really any cause.  Sodium benzoate is not remotely harmful in the concentrations that humans ingest.  [Here is the FDA's statement](http://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/GRAS/SCOGS/ucm260074.htm) on benzoates and benzoic acid.

There were claims that a mixture of ascorbic acid and benzoates would react to form benzene.  That has been shown to not be an issue.  There were ~100 drinks containing benzoates [tested by the FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Food/FoodborneIllnessContaminants/ChemicalContaminants/ucm055815.htm#table1), and only 5 showed benzene levels higher than allowed in drinking water.  These were reformulated and now show less than 5ppb benzene.  I would suspect that their benzene came from another source rather than this unlikely reaction, but I don't have any evidence for that.

Finally, neither Coke nor Pepsi even contain benzoate, benzoic acid, or any other compound that is chemically close to benzene.

Comment: ssavec indicated benzene can form when one drinks Coke or Pepsi and one has some ascorbic acid already injested and then benzene oxide can form when the body tries to get rid of the benzene. Benzene oxide can accumulate and alter gene expression.

Comment: So if one drinks orange juice in the morning and the Coke or Pepsi during the day (many drink a lot of pop drinks during the day) then benzene may form , the body the forms benzene oxide to get rid of the benzene. The benzene oxide is harmful..

Comment: @user128932 Who or what is ssavec and what evidence does he, she, or it have that benzene is formed from Coke or Pepsi in the body?  Why make the same comment twice?  Your claim seems to indicate that if we tested regular cola drinkers we should find significantly higher quantities of benzene oxide in their systems.  Can you cite a study that shows that?

Comment: ssavec is a user of this very stack exchange. The idea was that benzene may be formed when ascorbic acid and sodium benzoate is injested by a person. If you tested many cola drinkers who drink a lot of cola in one day benzene MAY form in their body and benzene oxide would be used by the person's body to get rid of the benzene. I didn't know this , I'm just reporting what @ssavec indicated.

Comment: you asked who or what is ssavec and I replied and then no comment. The user with the designation ssavec should be concerned.

Comment: I previously wrote a question 'About all the pop drinks being sold' regarding sodium benzoate and a person called ssavec responded about the biochemistry effects of benzene oxide. Someone previously said 'who or what is ssavec..'; users should read more of the relevent references in these sites before criticising someone else.

Comment: @user128932 And I was notified about your comments exactly 1 time, today.  Why assume that the system works as intended, or that people check this place every day?  Regarding the actual point you tried to make, you seem to not understand that Coke and Pepsi **do not contain sodium benzoate.**  Therefore, the proposed mechanism, benzoate + ascorbic acid cannot possibly happen in these beverages.  Moreover, I posted actual links to scientific studies by the FDA indicating that your proposed benzoate + ascorbic acid reaction was false.  You never provided *any* information to support your claim.

Comment: I wrote the reply above on Nov.16 , then I got a response on Nov. 26 , I was wondering before if I would get any further response. According to the Food Production Daily.com ,there is an article called 'Pepsi and other companies settle benzene lawsuit..' Written in 2007. According to Live Strong.com , an article 'What soft drinks have E211 in them . Regular Coke doesn't have it now but it's other products like Fanta and Sprite do. Pepsi max has E211( sodium benzoate) as does Sunkist Orange , Mountain Dew and Nestea. This article was updated in 2013. Wikipedia also has articles about this.

Comment: I looked up the user ssavec who has a reputation of 1,449 and has answered 51 questions. ssavec wrote on one of my other question about pop drinks that there is an article at hpa.org.uk/webc/hpawcb_c/1194947391801 about the toxicology of sodium benzoate. He also mentioned about benzoic acid. I noticed you said 'who or what is ssavec and what evidence does he ,she,or it have..' I suggest you look up such things before suggesting I was distorting info. or somehow stupid..

Comment: @user128932 If you feel that you have evidence to support a better answer than the one I provided, please write an answer of your own and post it.  Select it as the answer to your own question.  It's a perfectly legitimate thing to do.  Arguing in comments is not the purpose of this site.